# passing parameter to view from sp

Tags: view, sql-server-2012

I am using below query in my stored procedure.

`F_Chem_name` and `Language` are input parameters.

Is it possible to create a view for this below query and pass these input parameters to the view from stored procedure?.

How can i pass parameter to view from stored procedure?

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT F_PRODUCT
      ,n.F_CAS_NUMBER
      ,c.F_COMPONENT_ID
FROM dbo.PDF_MSDS

    CROSS APPLY (SELECT value as F_CAS_NUMBER
                 FROM STRING_SPLIT(F_CAS_NUMBERS, '¿')
                 WHERE value <> '') as n

    CROSS APPLY (SELECT value as F_COMPONENT_ID
                 FROM STRING_SPLIT(F_COMPONENT_IDS, '¿')
                 WHERE value <> '') as c
)
SELECT CTE.F_PRODUCT
      ,COM.F_Cas_Number
      ,COM.F_Component_Id
      ,COM.F_Chem_Name
FROM dbo.Components COM

    INNER JOIN CTE
        ON CTE.F_CAS_NUMBER = COM.F_Cas_Number
            AND CTE.F_COMPONENT_ID = COM.F_Component_Id

WHERE COM.F_Chem_Name LIKE @Chem_Name
    AND Language = @Language
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?  You can't pass parameters to a view, though you can apply a `where` filter once the view is defined and you are `select`ing data from it.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are:

1) create the view without the `WHERE` clause and specify the `WHERE` clause in the proc when selecting from the view

2) convert the view to a [table-valued function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql), passing the values as parameters.